# Monitor unused indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a set of servers where the maintenance query execution takes long. This is due to the indexes that are created by the developers at different points. Is there any way to monitor the unused indexes that adversely affect the execution.

Answer (score 16):

For mysql 5.6 before

By Default package of mysql does not have much statistics for analysis but there are some unofficial patches by which you can analyze.

like **userstats**  http://ourdelta.org/docs/userstats

By This patch you can analyze the stats and unused indexes.

Follow the below links to do that

https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/06/30/find-unused-indexes/

In MySQL 5.6 and later, the PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tracks index IO. If an index has no IO activity, it has not been used.

The sys schema now provides a convenient view to make it easier to identify unused indexes:

http://www.markleith.co.uk/2011/04/18/monitoring-table-and-index-io-with-performance_schema/

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS unused_indexes;

CREATE VIEW unused_indexes AS
SELECT object_schema,
   object_name,
   index_name
 FROM performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage 
 WHERE index_name IS NOT NULL
AND count_star = 0
ORDER BY object_schema, object_name;
```

*Note that this shows indexes that haven't been used since the last restart of mysqld. The PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA statistics are reset at startup time.*

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL version 5.7 and later, you can SYS schema to retrieve data either in raw format of user understandable format. SYS schema fetch the data from the underlying performance_schema and information_schema and present them in a better, understandable format. Refer [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys)

Comment: Thank you,I am currenlty using 5.7.9. Is there a way to fetch the unused indexes over a certain time automatically or send mails when unused indexes grow oversize?

Comment: You can use Custom SQL Objects to utilize information available in Information_Schema,Performance_Schema of MySQL 5.5+ and SYS schema of MySQL 5.7+ that are not exposed in the basic SHOW statements we have been using till now in the monitors/advisors. 

CSOs not only lets you monitor server metrics but also lets you monitor server data. Try https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog if you wish to monitor the Unused indexes that have no IO activity and also receive mail if any.You can use the this query to fetch the info,`SELECT object_schema,object_name,index_name FROM sys.schema_unused_indexes;`