# Get a MySQL index last use time?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a few tables with many indexes, that all have probably been useful at some point when designing the system, but with further updates to the codebase *may* have become useless.

**Is there a way to ask MySQL the last time it used a specific index to answer a query?**

This would save me from having to analyze every single query issued by my system to check what index(es) it might use (and also pinpoint what indexes are *really* used in production on the actual data).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993482/monitor-unused-indexes-in-mysql, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243475/how-do-you-identify-unused-indexes-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: @baao Thanks for the pointer, I did not find it myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only metric available is how much the index has been used since the last MySQL server restart, which perfectly fulfills my needs. [This answer in "Monitor unused indexes in MySQL"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34993822/759866) gives a query (MySQL 5.6+) to return indexes that have not been used since then:

```sql
SELECT object_schema, object_name, index_name
FROM performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage 
WHERE index_name IS NOT NULL AND count_star = 0
ORDER BY object_schema, object_name;
```

Thanks to @baao for the pointer.

Comment: Beware that according to documentation: `A DDL operation that changes the index structure of a table may cause the per-index statistics to be reset.`. So, if you have index1 and index2 and the query shows index2 is not used and you decide to drop index2, then if you run that query index1 might actually appear in results as if it's not used too.